# Query did not conform to expectations when querying with the dimension "sharingService"

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I am writing a ruby gem for the analytics API and ran into this error while trying to build the method for retrieving sharing services:

```
$ yt_session('https://www.googleapis.com').get("/youtube/analytics/v1/reports?ids=channel==7BCpCq_Vh2V0kVW28GTwGg&dimensions=sharingService&metrics=shares&start-date=2012-10-09&end-date=2012-10-10")

{ "error": {  "errors": [   {    "domain": "global",    "reason": "badRequest",    "message": "Invalid query. Query did not conform to the expectations."   }  ],  "code": 400,  "message": "Invalid query. Query did not conform to the expectations." }}
```

When I substitute the metrics and dimensions I have no issues.

I have been going off of the documents on this page: [YouTube Analytics Docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/available_reports)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a very helpful error message, but my assumption is that at least one of your problems is that your `channel==` parameter is incorrect. Channel ids are prefixed with UC, so you'd want to pass in `ids=channel==UC7BCpCq_Vh2V0kVW28GTwGg`

Does that resolve it for you?

Comment: This was a long time ago and I haven't looked into resolving it, but @Jeff I noticed through the API and various calls that most if not all calls work without the UC, but not all calls work with the UC prefixed.

Comment: Well, in v3 and the Analytics API, UC+userid has a very specific meaning—it's the channel id and it's how you uniquely identify channels (you can't use the legacy YouTube username). v1/v2 has a lot more "flexibility" and you can usually use the legacy YouTube username, the UC+userid value, or the bare userid value interchangeably. Maybe that's what you're seeing?